# ColdFusion 9.01 on Java 7

Tags: java, coldfusion, java-7, coldfusion-9

Is there a list of what is broken when trying to Run ColdFusion 9.01 on Java 7?

I have experienced issues with PDF generation.

This Link: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/java-7-support-for-coldfusion suggests that it is related to textarea on PDF

But is there a complete list of known issues?

Comment: Adobe have promised to provide a Java 7 support update by the end of the month - why not wait four days for that update, instead of wasting time on things that are potentially fixed.

Comment: Is that update still anticipated to be at the end of the month?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Have you heard anything to suggest it'll be late?

Comment: I have heard nothing to suggest it is late. I have heard nothing to suggest that things are moving on time. I have heard nothing about if there will be a 9.03 release or a 10.01(?) release. I have heard nothing about performance improvements (if any). I have heard a lot of nothing.

Comment: Here you go: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/new-updates-for-coldfusion-9-9-0-1-9-0-2-and-10-java-7-now-supported

Comment: Looks like there will be a CF 9.01 Hotfix 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 1.7 Update 15 is now officially supported with Cumulative Hotfix 3 (now superseded by 4)

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-3-coldfusion-901.html

Answer (score 1):

It's just like the others said. Right now, only Java 6 is officially supported.

Adobe has announced a change for Java 7 support, but there hasn't been anything solid yet.

In the meantime, check out http://bloginblack.de/2013/02/another-java-security-baseline-update-coldfusion-railo-and-others/ for more on the topic and why you should update to the latest version of Java 6 in the meantime.

Comment: I see that the link has a link which on 2/25/13 states: "... We will have an update released before the end of this month and the Java 7 support and announcement will go out with the update. ..."

Comment: Yes, that's what Adobe promised. But since Adobe's promises in that regard are usually about as reliable as those made by some sleazy politician I wouldn't put any faith in that until there's actual proof.