# Coldfusion site stopped working after updating JRE1.6->JRE1.7

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am getting

```
"Information","localhost-startStop-1","04/09/15","10:13:36",,"ColdFusion started"
"Error","localhost-startStop-2","04/09/15","10:13:48",,"The Cron service is not available. This exception is usually caused by service startup failure. Check your server configuration."
```

after updating from x64 JRE1.6 to x64 JRE1.7u25

My neo-cron.xml isn't damaged and all works hen I switch back to 1.6

I'm on Coldfusion 9,0,1,274733 Enterprise

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked for patches/upgrades for ColdFusion?

Comment: What version of CF are you using? Versions of CF9 required a hotfix to allow 1.7 to work correctly.

Comment: I'm on 9,0,1,274733  Enterprise

Comment: useful info to include would be, what package of the jre/jdk did you download? where did you extract it to? did you make sure the bin folder is at the level in the folder structure you think it is? what did you modify your jvm.config file to say? what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ColdFusion 9.01 on Java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056729/coldfusion-9-01-on-java-7)

Answer (score 2):

Patch your system up-to-date using the Unofficial Updater and it should work again:

http://www.uu-2.info/

Comment: the UU2 complains about being able to service only 8.0.x and 9.0.x, I have 9.0.1. I am trying to hotfix with Cumulative hotfix3 from Adobe, but I can't get Java to unblock the "select file applet".